How do I make 3D voronoi mesh using geo nodes?

I am looking to create something like this using geometry nodes but not just across the surface of my mesh, but fully filled with simple voronoi texture pattern in 3 dimensions. Couldn't find a tutorial for this.

By fully filled, do you mean like bone marrow, swiss cheese or a sponge?

All of the above XD

Voronoi Volume
We can't plug a Voronoi texture directly into a Mesh to Volume node density, but we can with a Volume Cube, this offers us better possibilities for controlling how the Voronoi will be applied. So, connecting the voronoi to the cube, we get it split into voronoi cells like the Cell Fracture modifer.
Since we don't want just volume cube, we can use the Raycast when we import the target object and make some calculations so only the area that is hit by the Raycast, our object, will be represented by the volume density.
So that the volume cube will adjust to the size of the object, it must always be larger,  we can use a bounding box.
The approach is the same as if we were trying to emulate a cell fracture in geometry nodes and apply it to an imported object.

Once we have that done, the remaining nodes are a lot like the Remesh Modifier.  In other words, the rest is adjusting the values of the Voronoi, the Volume Cube resolution, and the Voxel Amount on a Volume to Mesh node, to your taste- so that this 'remesh' comes out with nice balance of dense matter and porous tunnels in the mesh.
Subdivision surface and smoothing help to round off some the voxel edges.

The Result after adding some materials looks something like this;
Here is the imported object and the modified object:


Voronoi Extruded Surface
In my example, we are starting with an icosphere with 8 subdivisions.
I will explain the most interesting nodes for me in the following tree.
There is a Voronoi Texture in geometry nodes.
It has a Distance to Edge setting which is useful because it has an output which can be used as a selection.  It is filtered through a Greater Than node to select what parts of the geometry to delete and consequently enables you to thicken the edges as they are extruded.
Another feature of this tree is the "Blur Attribute" node, which is used in this tree to round what would otherwise be jagged or pixelated geometry.



The first generation technique is covered in a tutorial by Jakob Design on Youtube is called "Easy Organic Dome in Blender with Geometry Nodes"
